# How to add batch commands to cmd.exe's PATH

Tags: windows-10, bash, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Ubuntu on Windows and in the bash I've installed g++. How do I make it available to normal Windows programs? How do I add it into the Windows `PATH`?

Since it's possible to execute bash commands using `bash -c "g++"`, I thought I could create a file called `g++.bat` containing `bash -c "g++ %*"` and add it to the `PATH`, but then there would be a problem with escaping quotes, right?

Comment: Peanut gallery (I haven't used the Windows Subsystem for Linux) but wouldn't the simple answer be not to use quotes (i.e. use paths without spaces)?

Comment: Well since `g++` is a compiler used by lots of software I didn't write, than sadly no. Or at least it would require rewriting the software so it would cease to be the simple answer anymore...

Comment: For your first question - adding to the Windows `PATH` - this can be done in the system properties. Press Win+Break -> Advanced system settings -> "Environment Variables..." and edit the `PATH` value.

As for your second question - it's a duplicate of [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an alias for `g++` into cmd:

1. Install [easyWSLbash](https://github.com/leongrdic/easyWSLbash) and add it to `PATH`

   - It is a simple utility that simplifies `bash -c "command"` to `b command`.
2. Create a file containing `b g++ %*` and save it as `g++.bat`
3. Add it to `PATH`.
4. Profit!

You can change `g++` to any command of your choice.